# Maven build zip file from generated resources

Tags: maven

How I can build zip file from generated resources?

Trying to generate a zip file for all generated files under target. Not sure where the problem is: 
assembly:

```
<id>resources-bundle</id>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/</outputDirectory>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/target/dependency/**.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

pom entry:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <id>archive</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                        <formats>
                            <format>zip</format>
                        </formats>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

error I'm facing:

```
Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive test-libs: You must set at least one file.
```

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The obvious question is: are there any properties file matching `**/target/dependency/**.properties`?

Comment: Yeah, this's also part of maven goal...these files expected to be fetched from dependent components. May be I need to to order these two goal yet not sure,

Comment: So there are no files matching this pattern, explaining the error message. Set the correct phase for each of your plugin so that they can be run in the correct order.

Comment: Even after I changed the phase to `<phase>package</phase>`, still facing same issue.

Comment: We'll need to see more of your POM.  Include the parts that should be copying the dependencies to the target location.

Comment: In the assembly descriptor, why is it **.properties?  Does *.properties work?

Comment: I doubted that this's not finding generated resources, when I added new fileset as follow 

    <fileSets>
  <fileSet>
   <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/</outputDirectory>
   <directory>${project.basedir}/</directory>
   <includes>
    <include>*.properties</include>
   </includes>
  </fileSet>
  <fileSet>
   <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/</outputDirectory>
   <directory>${project.basedir}/</directory>
   <includes>
    <include>readme.txt</include>
   </includes>
  </fileSet>
 </fileSets>

then zip file getting generated but not icluding my properties in it

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
assembly.xml::

```
        <fileSet>
        <outputDirectory>resources/</outputDirectory>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/target/dependency/</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/**.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
```

pom.xml:

```
<execution>
                    <id>pack-resources</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                        <formats>
                            <format>zip</format>
                        </formats>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Thanks